# Entityframework navigation property insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have these models that ParentID foreign key for CustomerID
I want to insert an address for customer via navigation property
what should I do?

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public long CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public partial class Address
{
    public long AddressID { get; set; }
    public long ParentID { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain more?!

Comment: Configure correctly. Build the object. Add the object to the context. Save Changes. Any more questions?

Comment: It's one to many relationship. How would you normally add if it is pure SQL? you create new record for 'one' side first, then you add a record for 'many' side with a key references to the newly created 'one'. Follow that pattern, make sure you call SaveChanges()

Comment: Jacky Nguyen: Actually, it doesn't really matter to EF from which side records are inserted, but from the "many" side he sure has to pay attention to not add the object twice... which might be a problem anyways, looking at the relationships.

Comment: the OP code doesn't have any annotation, so I am assuming he is using fluent api to config the relationship. Also, for one-to-many, the side does matter. The address can surely be alone without having ParentID assigned. But if he wants to establish the relationhsip, a ParentID must exist so he must add a new Customer(one side) first.

Comment: It can configure by convention as well. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962